# Reason for "could not find implicit value for parameter rs: spray.routing.RoutingSettings"

Tags: scala, spray

While exactly following (or so I thought) the example at https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.3/src/main/scala/com/example/MyService.scala I ran into this error:

```
[error] /Users/alias/dev/src/main/scala/framework/MyActor.scala:86: could not find implicit value for parameter rs: spray.routing.RoutingSettings
[error]   def receive = runRoute(routes)
[error]
```

and couldn't figure out why the seemingly same code didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/oc1NlWQ362k) which pointed me in the right direction for debugging the issue using `implicitly`

```
implicitly[RoutingSettings]
```

From there I was able to determine that there was an ambiguous implicit

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - implicit ActorRefFactory required: if outside of an Actor you need an implicit ActorSystem, inside of an actor this should be the implicit ActorContext
    - not enough arguments for method default: (implicit refFactory: akka.actor.ActorRefFactory)spray.routing.RoutingSettings. Unspecified value parameter 
     refFactory.
    - ambiguous implicit values: both value context in trait Actor of type => akka.actor.ActorContext and method system in trait ActorContext of type => 
     akka.actor.ActorSystem match expected type akka.actor.ActorRefFactory
```

Which I eventually worked out was being caused by `import context._` in my Actor

This took me FAR too long to work out, so hopefully this will save people a lot of time in future!

Comment: But did you just remove the import or what? Scala is complaining to me if I remove either!

Answer (score 1):

try to add: `def actorRefFactory = context`

Comment: I had that in there, it was the conflict from having the 2 implicits in scope that matched ActorRefFactory (ActorContext and ActorSystem)